# European Tachograph Company Smart Card returns 6D00

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu, pcsc

We are busy trying to remotely authenticate between a tachograph company smart card and a tachograph. We got it working with our test tachograph but now we encountered a problem with a live one.

Whenever we start the authentication, things go pretty well until the Tachograph sends a get response command: `00C0000080`. The Tachograph smart card responds with `6D00`. In other words (as I understand it), the tachograph requests a GET response from the smart card. And the smart card answers with "CLA supported, but INS invalid or not programmed" (found in the documentation).

I tried forcing the T1 protocol. Doesn't change the outcome. We tried forcing the T0 protocol, but the smart card is not read by my software anymore. This means the T0 protocol is apparently not supported on this smart card.

Does anyone have an idea what this problem means?

### EDIT

It was requested that I place the order of commands by Maarten, see the following lines of commands:

1. card gives ATR: `3BDF960080B1FE451F870031C16408923201738421E0059000C5`
2. tacho responds: `00A4020C020002`
3. card responds: `9000`
4. tacho responds: `00B0000009`
5. card responds: `000103492B022104309000`
6. tacho responds: `00A4040C06FF544143484F`
7. card responds: `9000`
8. tacho responds: `0022C1B60A8308000DAA06111606A2`
9. card responds: `9000`
10. tacho responds: `0088000010011EBDDCAFA17487000DAA06111606A2`
11. card responds: `9000`
12. tacho responds: `00C000008000`
13. card responds: `6700`
14. tacho responds: `00C0000080`
15. card responds: `6D00`
16. end of all comms

For Maarten: You may assume that the software works correctly. This is live data from a truck this afternoon. The electronics device is wired to the Tacho and my software (that has the readers inserted physically server side) communicates with the electronics device. This device is made by another programmer and he assured me that the data going to and coming from the tacho is communicated correctly. I know that my piece of the software communicates correctly with the smart card, as we got it all working with another card and tacho.

### EDIT #2

After we found that some error in the internal authenticate command appeared, we tried forcing a hex byte `80` behind the internal authenticate command. Which makes the process go further, but still cancel after a read binary. Don't know for sure why it does, but we are looking into it at the moment. APDU's below.

1. comms start, the card sends atr: `3BDF960080B1FE451F870031C16408923201738421E0059000C5`
2. tacho responds: `00A4020C020002`
3. card responds: `9000`
4. tacho responds: `00B0000009`
5. card responds: `000103492B022104309000`
6. tacho responds: `00A4040C06FF544143484F`
7. card responds: `9000`
8. tacho responds: `0022C1B60A8308000DAA06111606A2`
9. card responds: `9000`
10. tacho responds: `0088000010A73D4B33337EBC3D000DAA06111606A280`
11. card responds: `1C90A7F7796CC9B2082470504DCDCF3D3E9EEDEEE00F4AF1FCA127CC1D7B746D21C63DA4D75138B61D7715C4919B37601BF8897DB7C1DD5F58309D55B9588C007AFBA22F997523300B1351684F65AB5FA59E350295B7EE1170F934FC8AFE191E9DEEEDBF7C582D7D0709FEE0F1B44EF3C9D452AB8F25B1106B1E510EF956D6E79000`
12. tacho responds: `0084000008`
13. card responds: `2DA8A7836A6FCF1A9000`
14. tacho responds: `00820000800E5EE3CBE4F16EC816E3FB198F86338604455355AC6123E1B057C9A53ED356679B4F1AE34B8A2EBD95FDD96E4707CDECA208BF22BAA6F70A3ED0CCA39FCC6199B3F959F3226E018D46029142314F25A332C1666A44E9EE3616CD19F9A7E169827C3CEDED372F49A8478BCDD97E63EE48ED695EFFC9B556E4246732BB372C9714`
15. card responds: `9000`
16. tacho responds: `00A4020C020520`
17. card responds: `9000`
18. tacho responds: `0CB000000997018B8E04F0821140`
19. card responds: `9000`
20. tacho responds: `00A4020C020501`
21. card responds: `9000`
22. tacho responds: `0CB00003099701028E046733DD55`
23. card responds: `6688`
24. end of all comms

As you can see, we added `80` manually behind the internal authenticate command which made it go further but it still went wrong. We don't know for sure why it went wrong now,  Any ideas, or suggestions as to why the card is now responding with 6688 while a read binary should just return the info are most welcome. We are now on the track of thinking that the "Stonedidge" tacho works differently from the "VDO" tacho. The company/driver has not set the Tacho settings to remote CAN communication, causing errors. I will keep this question updated for later use and other people encountering the same problem.

### Solved (for now)

It turns out there is indeed a problem with Stoneridge tachographs. We think a Stoneridge needs to be configured by a workshop to enable remote authentication and download. We have some documentation that seems to confirm this. I will not explain how this is done as this kind of information is not meant for everybody. We did a live test today on another truck with a VDO tachograph (that does not need this configuration) and everything works smoothly and as expected following Appendix 11. If I don't forget, I will update this question when we configure the Stoneridge and get it working, so anybody else encountering this problem can try it as well.

Comment: Smart card need to be unlocked with a crypto key (certificate) before they can be used.  To test that you have an unlocking issue you can unlock with windows by using a File Explorer to access the card.  If you can read card with Explorer than it is unlocked and should work from you app.  The card will stay unlocked until you remove card or turn off pc.  If you get an error using window explorer than you are missing the driver from the card and/or the certificate is not loaded.

Comment: Yes I know. That is not the issue here. You see, the whole authentication process is done by the Tachograph and the smart card. Our software is just a man-in-the-middle that passes the commands along. This 6D00 is (as far as I understand) has nothing to do with authentication. As that is exactly what the tachograph and the smart card are doing in this process. It seems the card simply does not understand the APDU

Comment: There are lots of different smart card options 8/16/32/64 bit address and data modes.  The mode of how the card was formatted and the application has to be compatible.  Also you should be using a driver for the card that is compatible with the application.  And there are different versions of cards.  Older cards are only 8 bit and new cards which may be only 32/64 bit.  I usually start by recommending that use a vendor tools to get system working before you try c#.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to anwer but this is not the problem.

Comment: See page 25 of following.  I think it is the instruction is invalid.  Which could mean you are addressing the card in the wrong mode (8,16,32,64) or you have a little/big endian issue.  See : https://dtc.jrc.ec.europa.eu/iot_doc/EU%202018-502.pdf?force_isolation=true

Comment: Gonna look into it now. I also thought I addressed it in the wrong mode, but none of the other modes seem to make a change. The APDU I send from the card is not something I create myself, this is created automatically by the tachograph following the commmunication protocol. The only thing I can look into is the little/big endian issue, so that's usefull. Gonna check it out. thanks.

Comment: Did you check the ATR string returned by the card? There you can see whether it supports T0/T1, etc. One [online ATR decoder](https://smartcard-atr.apdu.fr/) can help. If you'r in the middle you can make a full communications dump and check.

Comment: Jup did, seems it supports both, unless the [C# libray](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) does not read it correctly.

Comment: Uh, now we get into strange territory, because the reader may just **choose** T = 0 if the card indicates that it supports it. Can you include the command + data **right before** the GET RESPONSE?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes see the edit! :) Do have to leave now, I'll get back to you as soon ASAP

Comment: Check the driver of the card. Make sure you are using the correct driver.  A generic driver may not work.  The driver has to be able to support the Smart Card Version of the card.  So you have to compare the card type and the driver.

Comment: Yeah, I'm Dutch. Uh, INTERNAL AUTHENTICATE (INS 88) should definitely have a response of 128 bytes (for the rather weak 1024 bit RSA key that they seem to still use). However, currently you're getting zero bytes response because the reader software doesn't ask for any. The GET RESPONSE is returned after a 9000 instead of a 61xx. Then you get a wrong length because you we see 8000 instead of 80 as Lc / Le byte. After that we see a 6D00 because the previous 6700 is the end of the command (it's an error), so it expect a new command rather than a GET RESPONSE. At least, that's how I interpret it.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean, "because the reader software doesn't ask for any"? I'm not sure I understand that part. As the Internal Authenticate command comes from the tacho. What I understand that after the Parameters, it encoded the number 16 for the data fields, then following the challenge data. After those 16 bytes, no Le field is present. Meaning the tacho does not expect a response.. right?

Comment: After looking at the interal authenticate command and other preceding commands together with the ISO 7816-4 documentation, I think I understand what you mean. Either the internal authenticate command is missing an LE byte, or the card is responding 9000 which shoudl have been 61xx where xx is the length of the reponse that is ready for the tacho... Maybe something is going wrong in our communication and the last bytes after the internal authenticate get lost, meaning the Le byte. gonna dig into this. Get back to you with furter questions or an answer (I hope)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes See edit! we went further, still looking into it now. thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I think you've solved your current question though; I'm sure that this status word is unrelated. Please try and keep things concise here; the complete debug session is yours alone :) Hint: CLA = Secure Messaging?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Helped an intern student a lot! :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Problem solved for now. Thanks again. Pretty difficult subject for an intern alone ;)

Comment: Pretty tricky & specialized subject for anyone, which is why they use interns ;) Make sure that you have a set of targets as well; you should not be there *just* to prove yourself (and doing all the work while you are it it). You should have a fresh copy of ISO 7816-4 provided to you.

Comment: Well, I'm done in 2 weeks, everything works on two test trucks (create software to read out smart cards, and then remotely authenticate and download a tachograph) and they offered me a job. Still have to graduate next schoolyear or so but at least I have a side job now, which is nice :) thnx dude!

Answer (score 2):

In T=1 the GET RESPONSE is (usually) not supported, as getting the response is part of the APDU transport layer. In T=1 you'd just stick the Le byte (now valued 0x80) to the end of the command requesting the data, making it a ISO CASE 2 (just response data) or 4 (command and response data present) command.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure I completely understand what you are saying. Do you mean I should rebuild the command? What should it look like? Main problem I have that this command comes automatically from a Tachograph following European protocol (dutch truck). I do not intervene in any way, I just pass the command along to the card. I can however catch these commands of coarse and restructure them as I think you suggest?

Comment: It looks like the the Tachograph thinks it needs to communicate using T=0 while your card only supports T=1. So you need to configure / trigger T=1 somehow in the reader (as you seem to be in between). Maybe you're passing a wrong ATR to the Tacho? The 0x80 needs to be appended to the **previous** command, the GET RESPONSE is just a bogus command to retrieve the response for a ISO CASE 4 as T=0 cannot handle both command and response data.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I've been trying. Everytime a smart card is inserted into my software, I tell it to use whatever (t0/t1). I then read out the ID section of the card so I can identify which card i'm dealing with for software purposes. Whenever I force it to use T0. It fails to read out the ID section. Meaning it seems like the Card does not support T0, which is weird as the card is created here in the Netherlands and the others that are do support it. So i seem to have to force the Tachograph to force T1 maybe, so it does not send get response but something else.

Comment: Well, in principle the response data should be the same for T=0 and T=1 so yeah, you could try and combine the initial command and the GET RESPONSE. However, I don't think there is a *generic* way to distinguish between CASE 3 (just command data) and 4, so there's that. The CASE 3 command might fail because it doesn't specify the max buffer size (Ne=0, through Le=absent) and the card wants to send data. Maybe it returns the data already in the previous command because this is implementation specific. In that case you could filter out the entire GET RESPONSE.

Comment: Uh, or just return the response data send with the previous command response ofd course, otherwise the Tacho might be waiting in vain.

Comment: Yes, but the combining would always be a hardcoded option, which is undesirable in this software application as it needs to interface with all kinds of different tachographs and cards. Meaning the combining is needed and sometimes its not needed, which you only find out after it goes wrong... Have to think on this a lot. Thanks for taking the time to answer, If you've got any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Well, if you indicate to the software that it is T=1 and T=0 commands are sent it is time to talk to the provider it seems. I hope it is not connected to me in some way :P

Comment: haha :P well to bad I can't seem to find a way to PB you, (as it seems you're dutch or European as well?) But it sure seems that way! The only other viable thing that is going wrong here is that the libray that i'm using (or the reader) doesn't return a correct ATR which i'm sending to the tacho. Meaning the ATR is just plain wrong and general. but the [parsing tool](https://smartcard-atr.apdu.fr/parse?ATR=3BDF960080B1FE451F870031C16408923201738421E0059000C5) sure seems to think it is a tachograph company card so there's that... :(