# Digital tachograph. Company card remote authentication error

Tags: smartcard, apdu, pcsc

I'm trying to perform remote authentication between a tachograph company smart card and an SE5000 tachograph.
I'm going through the path partially well, but after the key exchange, when I try to read the binary file, error 6E00 occurs.

Does anyone know what this problem means?

This is the order of commands between the card and the tachograph:

card gives ATR: 3BFC9600008031FE4380718065B0850400FB829000AA

tacho responds: 00A4020C020002

card responds: 9000

tacho responds: 00B0000009

card responds: 00310586EA082304219000

tacho responds: 00A4040C06FF544143484F

card responds: 9000

tacho responds: 0022C1B60A8308001DC0A0062306A2

card responds: 9000

tacho responds: 008800001095F3B213DC034C22001DC0A0062306A280

card responds: 5E8CC0BB5CE5E458E98BA257486EBE18F5653EBE7C6B6DB7517A3ED3814D08F30928B0FEF06E3FD4A8BFD8CA25A408C17D14DE2E3133C2E9076C1F3F90EE1DC8B4A827F2ACE7E452D8D0DE0D6E93A57B770435BB6D85E2ED53196448941A146FF464F23CED35CD61E1B2D878F296B2194646438CB9CFF142174CE64DB83E029C9000

tacho responds: 0084000008

card responds: 7C05CA4A8518DD749000

tacho responds: 00820000805119C3B026D8CC1FF3562E1089AFF5D567584506B7F7A1F723C445D7F9B013F0EB33150DAE197110B31F9F8914E878032295B25640B5E5EF55810C7BC609EEDDDDEDA8E1445BABF2C10D78503813A17071F531604C39444BC7CC880ECFB529247456F00105CAD29006C412D141D1AB950A2B76D6976359D3D218A558D3D10076

card responds: 9000

tacho responds: 00A4020C020520

card responds: 9000

tacho responds: 0CB000000997018B8E04B991986F

card responds: 6E00    //Class not supported

I made a request through the supplier to the tachograph manufacturer. But so far there is no answer.

[Stoneridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788005/european-tachograph-company-smart-card-returns-6d00/77177554#77177554)
It was said here that Stoneridge tachographs may require additional adjustments in the workshop. Does anyone know what needs to be configured?

Comment: Should be one more leading zero in the last tacho respond: 00CB00....  You have 0CB00... i.e. CLA=0C